# Mongo Db Replication error when Seconday node is down

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a problem in mongodb replication .

Whenever my replica server is down (which is secondary node). Then I can't read from master db (and I guess it should not happen, because master database is up and running ).

I have two micro services ....one is calling only the master db in node js like ----
Mongo.connect(masterurl)

If I hit any api in backend that is querying the database, I get the error

> not master or slave=false

And on the master db it shows ..connection refused to ip:port

But when the replica db is up then there is no error .

Master and replica are on different ip .

Thanks

Comment: How many secondary nodes do you have?

Comment: one secorndary node on the remote ip running under docker

Comment: If you only have 2 nodes in your replica set, when one goes down, the primary will step down and become secondary because it can no longer see a majority of the replica set.  At that point, only queries that permit secondary reads will be able to be processed.

Comment: what should i do to overcome this problem ...if i only want to have two nodes ...one primary in one server and one secondary in other server . and why does primary becomes seconday ...it should be primary ? right in every case if it was initialized as primary

Comment: see [Replica Set Primary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-primary/index.html#replica-set-primary).  The primary is determined by election, not by configuration, and there will only be a primary if a majority of the replica set is available

Comment: so you are saying there is no way in which if a secondary node is down ...then master node will continue to be primary node and serve all the request as it is

Comment: Only was is to have more than 2 nodes, that's why the recommendation is to always have an odd number of members.

Comment: okay ..got it ... but i think it can create disk space issues when two docker container with both secondary will run in one server

Answer (score 1):

If you have a two-node replica set, and one of the nodes is unavailable, the replica set does not have a primary. In order for a primary to exist in the RS, the majority of nodes must be available and communicating (so that they can elect the primary).

> Then I can't read from master db (and i guess it should not happen , bacause master db is up and running ).

The "master db" is not a MongoDB concept, so this statement is meaningless in the context of MongoDB.

If you wish to run MongoDB in resource constrained environments, consider a [PSA setup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-architecture-three-members/#primary-with-a-secondary-and-an-arbiter-psa) which comes with reduced redundancy and fault tolerance compared to PSS.